# Running Samsung Smart TV project in emulator causes a crash

Tags: emulation, samsung-smart-tv, television

I am trying to develop for Samsung smart tv. I have installed the Samsung SDK with Apache provided, and create a default project form template "Samsung Smart Tv Basic App" and I can't succeed to run my app to emulator.
When I run the project from **'Samsung Smart Tv SDK -> Run Project in Samsung TV Emulator'** the Samsung emulator opens automatically and crashes.

It this may happen because the code is incomplete and something is missing or I have to do some supplementary configurations. e.g. to set the Apache server.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think I found the reason, Emulator 2013 is not working.

Comment: It's not working, I encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is also plugin for Eclipse which works fine. Download here: http://www.samsungdforum.com/devtools/sdkdownload

However the 2012 and 13 both crashes during development sometimes if exceptions occur.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar occurrence with SDK 4.0/4.1 and Emulator 2013. It crashed on load.

The problem was with the video card, it was to old and it did not support DX.

I've put in a NVidia 6600GT and installed the latest drivers and it works now. Good luck.